# Selenium PageFactoryInit - Good Practices. What would be the good way to return new page?

Tags: java, selenium

```
public HomePage LoginAs(String user,String password){
        userName.sendKeys(user);
        psswd.sendKeys(password);
        signIn_btn.click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
    }
   // return PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);Or 
  // return new HOmePage(driver)
```

creating a new object of `HomePage` class and Initializing in the //constructor like below.

```
public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);          
    }
```

What would be a good standard approach? Does both of them would result same?

Answer (score 0):

There's not much difference between the two.

In my opinion, the latter is more readable, since `return new HomePage();` is self-explanatory. Nevertheless, the problem with this approach is when you use a base class like:

```
public abstract class Page {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public Page(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this); 
    }
}
```

And your `HomePage` extends it, when you'll call `new HomePage();` you'll get in an infinite loop. So personally I stick with the `return PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);`

Answer (score 0):

I will go with the second option because it is more logical and more readable, However I will also recommend converting it to

```
return new HomePage();
```

as it is more readable, you can do this using a static class for the driver, or you can find any other way that makes you able to get rid off the driver passing, tester should be able to write the test even he knows nothing about selenium
I recommend something like:

```
public static class Browser
{
  public static IWebdriver Driver = new whateverBrowser();
}

public class BasePage
{
 public BasePage()
 {
  PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver,this);
 }
}
public class HomePage:BasePage
{

}
```